# Definitions of Knot Theory

Tags: knot-theory

I am currently doing a course in Knot Theory and after looking at different texts I have found many ways to define knots and knot equivalence. In our course we are given the following definitions:

A ***knot*** $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is a subset of the form $K=f(\mathbb{R})$ where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is a map with the following properties.

1. $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})$ if and only $x_{1}-x_{2}\in\mathbb{Z}$
2. The derivative $\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}f$ exists for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
3. The derivative is not zero everywhere, $\frac{df}{dx}\neq 0$

Knots $K$ and $K^{\prime}$ are ***equivalent*** if there exists a collection of knots $K_{x}$ for each $x\in\left[ 0,1\right]$. such that $K_{0}=K$ and $K_{1}=K^{\prime}$, and such that there exists a smooth map $F:\left[ 0,1\right]\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with the property that $F(x,\cdot )$ represents $K_{x}$ in the sense of the previous definition.

I think I understand intuitively what is happening here and that this smooth map ensures that we make no illegal 'jumps'. I am at the same time taking a course in Algebraic Topology and for the sake of my note keeping I would like to give an alternative definition of equivalence more in line of homeomorphisms from Topology, which If im not mistaken is essentially what is going on here.

So I would say that two knots $K$ and $K^{\prime}$ are equivalent if there exists a homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$ for which $f(K)=K^{\prime}$.

Would this definition be satisfactory, if not how could I change it? Is there any substantial difference from my definition and the one given by my lecturer?

Comment: Left and right trefoils aren't equivalent, but isn't reflection a homeomorphism taking one to the other?

Comment: Ah, very true. Is there some way I can ask for a homeomorphism which preserves left and right handness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, you need to differntiate mirror images to agree with your first definition. This is fixed by asking for an orientation-preserving homeomorphism $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory#Knot_equivalence, where it is also (briefly) explained why these two notions of equivalence are the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see now how these coincide, and how I must define it.